# How to deform a shape along a path using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, shapes

I know that it is possible to write a text along a path.

> I want to know is it possible to draw a shape along a path?

I know that this is impossible in most cases. but I think we can draw such shape for simple shapes like rectangle, circle, cube, ...e.g. suppose we have a circle inside a rectangle (distortion sample). by curving the edges of rectangle I want circle deformed proportionately. something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is what `nonlinear transformations` are good for.

Comment: This is a `Tikz` library?

Comment: A pgf module. There is also `curvilinear` that allows you to transform something along a path.

Comment: Your profile image, the cat has a mask!! you are very up to date.

Comment: Yes, I had to put it on because so many humans do not seem to understand what social distancing means....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve something of that sort.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu} 
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\tikzset{declare function={xtransformed(\x,\y)=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/trafos/a}*
    sign(\x)*\y*\y;},
trafos/.cd,a/.initial=pi}
\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myy}{\pgf@y}%
\PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myx}{\pgf@x+xtransformed(\pgf@x/1cm,\pgf@y/1cm)}%\typeout{(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)|->(\myx pt,\myy pt)}
\pgf@x=\myx pt%
\pgf@y=\myy pt%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=pi/2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}
\draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=pi/2];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the `curvilinear` library, but I think if you want to use it you'd need to split the picture in two halfs.